# some elementary linear algebra questions about direct sum and span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

**I am stuck on Question 2(b)(iii). For (i) and (ii) I've showed that (0,0,0) is not uniquely expressed and hence false. I think (iii) is true but I don't know how to show it.
And for Question5, could you please check my workings?**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For 2.b(iii):

$$(1,-2,1)\in W\cap V\neq\{0\}\implies\;\text{the sum cannot be direct}$$

For 5.a: your supposed counter example is wrong, since

$$\text{Sp}\,S\cap\text{Sp}\,T=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\;;\;(x,y)=r(1,0)=s(0,1)\;,\;r,s,\in\Bbb R\}=\{0\}$$

For 5.b: again you have a mistake, since for example

$$(0,1)\in\{(0,y)\;;\;y\in\Bbb R\}\cup\{(x,0)\;;\;x\in\Bbb R\}$$

But you can mend this easily: just show that $\;(1,1)\;$ does *not* belong to the union.

For 5.c:

$$x\in\text{Sp}(S\cup T)]\implies x=\sum a_is_i+\sum b_jt_j\;,\;\;a_i,b_j\in\Bbb R\;,\;s_i\in S\;,\;t_j\in T$$

and the first sum is in Sp$\,S$ and the second one's in Sp$\,T$.

OTOH...this is for you. And remember: it is **always** finite sums in each case, of course

Comment: thanks alot. for 2.b.iii, would S = {(1,0,0), (0,1,0)} and T ={(1,1,0)} work?

Comment: There is no S,T in 2...did you mean something else?

Comment: oh sorry. I meant for Q5a.

Comment: Oh, I see...yes, that'd be a good counter example. Nice.